# Graphics problem with emacs after upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 22.04, window, emacs

When I open emacs in 22.04 LTS the window has a graphics problem, some colored runes on black background but no text. I'm working in a Virtual Box on a Windows 10 host. The problem occured after a double upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and then 22.04 but also on a fresh installation of 22.04 LTS (128MB graphics memory, 3D hardware support). On the 18.04 I had emacs 25 installed and it worked perfectly. I tried to uninstall and then reinstall several times, using the command line and the software center, snap or a normal package, emacs 27 or 29. Other software seems work without any problem.

[The faulty emacs window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaNud.png)